# Why is {}+{} in the same browser works have different results

Tags: javascript, web, browser, ecmascript-5

I'm in the Google browser console run is like this

{}+{}    =>  "[object Object][object Object]"

[image]

But I run in the source file is like this

{}+{}    =>  NaN

[image]
I'm in the firefox browser console run is like this
{}+{} => NaN

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was preparing another answer that basically said, "I don't know but here are some tests that I done and got similar results". But suddenly I realized the real answer.

I think this is somewhat an undefined behaviour in javascript syntax. Chrome console developers maybe were aware of this and whenever you write `{}+{}` in console, it turns the code into `({}+{})`. Try `({}+{})` or `a={}+{}` and you will get the same result everywhere which is `"[object Object][object Object]"`. That is the result of applying plus operator to two objects in javascript.

When you write some code in snippet however, it is eval'ed as it is. And it calculates `{}+{}` as `NaN`. But `NaN` is not the result of adding two objects. `{}` is object constructor literal. But it is also used to scope. So what is evaluated is equal to:

```
{ // Open scope
  // You can write any working code here
  // Only the result of the last statement is printed to console
} // Close scope
+{} // Result of this is NaN
// + is the unary number cast operator not the binary addition operator
```

You can confirm this by using an operator that is only unary. Take this for example:

```
{}~{}
// Error in Chrome console as it is turned into ({}~{}) which is bad syntax
// -1 in eval as it is the result of ~{}
```